# How to merge pull requests to original repository into forked repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have forked the `gobuster` repository on GitHub to add new functionality to it:

https://github.com/OJ/gobuster

Now, since the maintainers of `gobuster` seem to have somewhat abandoned the tool, I have decided to add some functionality currently present in pull requests to my fork, e.g. (`#89`):

https://github.com/OJ/gobuster/pull/89

How can I merge pull requests to the original repository into my fork?

*This is the first time, I'm trying to perform such operation; normally, I just use `git` to commit changes to my own repositories*

Comment: Push a copy of [the contributor's fork's branch](https://github.com/rtheory/gobuster/tree/ExtensionsOnly) to your own repo, then you can make your own PR from that branch.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. Can't I just directly merge the commit into my own repo without pushing the branch to it? Why would I make a PR to myself?

Comment: You can't change the target repo and branch of someone else's PR.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, but can't I convert someone else's PR into a PR that I can just merge into my own repository? Why would I create my own PR, when I already have the contributer's fork's branch in my own repo?

Comment: Because the PR doesn't exist in git, just in GitHub. You have the _branch_ in your repo, you have to create your own _PR_ for it in GH.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, but only if I want to create a pull request for original `gobuster`, right?

Comment: Oh I see, sorry - you could just merge that branch _without_ a PR, yes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. I cloned the contributer's fork locally, and then pushed to my local repository using `git push ../gobuster ExtensionsOnly`. Worked perfectly!